# C3.js (Bar chart) axis label position not working when rotated: true

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, c3.js

Axis label position for different options like `position:` '`outer-left'/outer-center/outer-left`..... not working if axis rotated: true.
[Here is the jsfiddle link..](http://jsfiddle.net/sipu/7kYJu/1693/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the axies are rotated, you should invert the position.

http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/1742/

```
axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
    label: {
        text: 'X Label',
        position: 'outer-middle'
    }
},
    y: {
    label: {
        text: 'Y Label',
        position: 'outer-center'
    }
}
```

Here, X position and Y position attribute has been inverted.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and perfect replay.

Comment: is there any way to put Legends on top like Nvd3 charts http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/1743/ : You can only put the legend on the bottom, the right, or inset. 
ref: http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-position

Comment: Right now they have no option to show legends on top.Any way to sort simple bar charts ascending or descending order, if we will not use group options on Stacked Bar Chart ?